# Can QtRuby applications be deployed on Apple's App Store?

Tags: ruby, app-store, macruby, qtruby

I'm debating whether I should go with MacRuby or QtRuby. I definitely want to deploy my app on the App Store, however. If QtRuby cannot be deployed on the App Store, I will have to use MacRuby.